# Content not showing on browser On flutter web

Tags: google-chrome, flutter, flutter-web

i Created a flutter web and when i am running the web app using "Flutter run -d chrome " is not showing any error instead it opens up browser with no content

Here is the source code: [https://bitbucket-students.deakin.edu.au/scm/~mvarghese/medicalsaas.git](https://bitbucket-students.deakin.edu.au/scm/%7Emvarghese/medicalsaas.git)

[This is output from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSLVl.png)

[This is output from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ann4D.png)

Comment: Did you later fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try switching channel :

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter run -d chrome
```

[Channels details](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels)